Synchronize to coded signal for detection
Forgive my ignorance of terminology.
I've achieved synchronous demodulation (lock-in amplification) of an optically transmitted code a few years back, i.e. transmit and integrate whatever gets picked up by the receiver, cancelling out noise and ambient light.
When transmitter and receiver are separate, can synchronization be achieved?
Could the receiver continuously try to detect some fixed (preamble) code and adjust its timing?
Would this work without phase detection (apparently requiring a harmonic signal)?
What is it called?


When transmitter and receiver are separate, can synchronization be achieved?

Since communication technology works: yes!

Could the receiver continuously try to detect some fixed (preamble) code and adjust its timing?

That is one of the methods used in timing synchronization, yes.

What is it called?

Preamble detection, I'd say, for the detection of the presence of a preamble. It depends a bit on the context, but I'd call a synchronization technique built on this preamble-based timing recovery.
In a purely additive uncorrelated noise channel, the detection method with the best performance is known, it's correlation. (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality lets us deduct that we can't make the detector SNR any better than by finding the inner product with a signal that's identical or a multiple of the preamble, and the inner product for energy-bounded signals the way we usually deal with them is correlation).
This belongs into the category of non-blind synchronizers, because it assumes knowledge on specific properties of the signal (not just stochastic properties), in this case the preamble.

Would this work without phase detection (apparently requiring a harmonic signal)?

The fact that you can detect the phase at the receiver through the correlation is a side-product here; the optimal timing is reached for a maximum magnitude, which ignores the phase.

So synchronization through correlation in a "preamble-based timing recovery in non-blind synchronizers" probably requires either a lot of memory or a lot of time (unless the signal is so strong it has high correlation straightaway)? I'll see what I can find in literature, unless you have some recommendations ...

"lot of" is very relative. I'd go with "no, this is relatively normal effort, because a preamble will be designed with something to detect it in mind". Literature: hm, the simplest timing recovery schemes (like this, it's basically the simplest to explain) taught in the basic communications engineering courses at some universities, but most will leave synchronization up to advanced courses. So, the standard book on synchronization is Mengali, but you probably won't find a copy for sale. Not sure what literature you need, though – "correlate until you find a peak" isn't really something that…

… needs a lot of elaboration. Error probabilites in AWGN and other channels, OK, that's where it gets more intense, but then you would need a solid foundation in comms engineering. So, the standard comms engineering books would work.
